# Unit testing mapstruct with 'uses'

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

Is there a standard approach for unit testing mappers when using spring boot? i.e. getting dependencies etc.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {VehicleMapper.class, VehicleMapperImpl.class,
  VehicleAttributesMapper.class, VehicleAttributesMapperImpl.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class VehicleMapperTest {

@Autowired
private VehicleMapper vehicleMapper;
```

VehicleMapper has a **uses**:

`@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = VehicleAttributesMapper.class)`

However when I run my unit test the `VehicleAttributesMapper` does not appear to get invoked? (the types match i.e. source/target)

TIA

Comment: Have you stepped through the mapper code? Please post the generated mapper code, the full code of your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned out that I needed to add an explicit mapping in the VehicleMapper:

`@Mapping(source = "vehicleInfo", target = "vehicleAttributes")`

I had thought that this would not need to be done explicitly. In the [docs](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers) under  "*Invoking other mappers*" it seems to suggest you don't (in the example anyway).

Comment: You don't need to do that when the names of the properties are same. When they are different you always need to do that. Didn't you see the unmapped target properties warning?

Comment: @Filip Thanks ~ if it did I must have missed it! As an aside thanks for developing a great product, I find it really nice to use.

Comment: You can experiment woth `Mapper#unmappedTargetReportPolicy`. It can cause a compilation error if you forget a property